# Mouse left click not working in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, mouse

I know this is an old problem. I have tried different solutions but only the ctrl-alt-F1 and ctrl-alt-F7 worked. In a working day, I have to do that hundreds of times. What is the cause of this? Is there a better way to fix it by now?

I saw similar post on Ubuntu 18.04. So upgrade seem to have no effect.

[Mouse left click stops working](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/369097/mouse-left-click-stops-working)