# No Primary Mouse Button or Touch-screen on Ubuntu 19.10 and 20.04

Tags: mouse, touch-screen

Fresh install of both onto an older HP desktop all-in-one Touchsmart PC but no primary left mouse button. After seeing it wasn't working on 19.10 and having 20.04 come out around the same time, I reinstalled rather than upgraded but it still doesn't work. To test the mouse itself, I tried changing to left-hand and then it is the right button that won't work so clearly not a hardware issue.

I have tried the various things [shown here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/369097/mouse-left-click-stops-working) but nothing seems to work. However, copying and pasting some of the results has proven difficult without the mouse working and I have no other to use with it. The Keyboard also seems intermittent, working at times but seemingly dead moments later. Both wireless mouse and keyboard have new batteries and work perfectly in Windows.

Secondarily and not as important, the HP Touchsmart touch-screen isn't working. I know Ubuntu can handle touchscreens as I have a PC at another location which has one and it works.

Since this appears to be a more universal issue than just for the Ubuntu versions, I am posting here in the event that there is a fix.

Comment: From what I see online, I’m not alone by far on the mouse button issue which apparently has been happening through many Ubuntu versions so surprised at lack of responses! Surely by now there’s been a fix.

Comment: Anything on this? No different with 21.04. Also, screen is almost too dim to see unless room is very dark.